# Dealing with "see who voted on my questions" posts

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

This question has been asked at least twice today. I'm wondering should the explanation as to why it is not implemented be put into the FAQ? Although if a user doesn't go through the related questions, or even the front page they are hardly likely to read the FAQ. Should they be downvoted (I can see some are)?

Answer (score 3):

If "How do I see who voted on me?" is not already in the FAQs, I say by all means add it as soon as possible.  Then we will have a canonical answer that we can use to flag all others as dupes.

Comment: Indeed, if the question is frequently asked (twice in one day meets that criterion) then it is by definition a FAQ.